convert object to mock stream
given below was my object class .here i am trying to convert this object class to mock stream
    public class WebHookBody
    {
        public string entryId { get; set; }
    }

i am trying to add mock on the below code but i can't
var wasCalled = false;
            
var mockStream = new Mock<Stream>();
mockStream.Setup(s => s.CanWrite).Returns(true);
mockStream.Setup(s => s.Write(It.IsAny<byte[]>(),
    It.IsAny<int>(),
    It.IsAny<int>())).Callback((byte[] bytes, int offs, int c) =>
    {
        wasCalled = true;
    });```

converted mock stream for a given object class


it's not really clear what you want to achieve here. What has the WebHookBody to do with your Stream? You're not using it anywhere. Do you want to serialize your object to the stream? If so where's your serializer?

For testing I would recommend using MemoryStream in most cases. Since this is a complete stream implementation, but is fast and easy to use.

I would suggest not using wasCalled variable. Instead you can use Verify method to assert that particular method was called:
[Test]
public void TestStreamMock()
{
    var mockStream = new Mock<Stream>();
    mockStream.Setup(s => s.CanWrite).Returns(true);

    mockStream.Object.Write([1, 2, 3], 0, 100);

    // Assert that Write was called at least once.
    mockStream.Verify(
        s => s.Write(
            It.IsAny<byte[]>(),
            It.IsAny<int>(),
            It.IsAny<int>()),
        Times.AtLeastOnce);
}

